# Namenode is taking much time to restart due to the presence of large umber of edit files

Tags: hadoop3

We are using hadoop open source. W hat is the solution for hadoop taking so much time for restarting namenode for merging edit files to fsimage and how will the edit files be deleted after merging?

Solution to merge the edit files periodically and remove the edit files which are merged.